# Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. How to fix?

Tags: reactjs

```
const entries = type == 'admin' ? AdminMenu : CitizenMenu;
    const [finalEntries, setFinalEntries] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        entries?.top?.map((element, index) => {
            if (element.permission === 'all')
                setFinalEntries([...finalEntries, element])
            else if (user?.permissions?.includes(element?.permission))
                setFinalEntries([...finalEntries, element])
        });
    }, [entries]);


    return (
        <div className="leftMenu">
            <MB flex dc>
                {finalEntries?.map((item, index) => menuButton(item, index))}
            </MB>
        </div>
    )
```

I have a component that looks like this (very simplified version):

Hi guys, how to fix this error?

Comment: What you posted is not enough to run as snippet, which makes it difficult for anyone to test/suggest a fix. A probable fix is to use `entries.length` as dependency but, again, I can't be sure without being able to run it. I suggest using codesandbox.io (or similar) to create a [mcve]. As a side note, a potential problem with your code is you're using `map` instead of `forEach`. When you're interested in side effects (like in the above case), use `.forEach()`. When you're interested in the result of mapping (a new array), use `.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating state in `map`. So you encountered this situation.

If your `entries.top` have 100 entries, then you called state update 100 times and this will cause 100 times re-rendering.

This is very bad.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        entries?.top?.map((element, index) => {
            if (element.permission === 'all')
                setFinalEntries([...finalEntries, element])
            else if (user?.permissions?.includes(element?.permission))
                setFinalEntries([...finalEntries, element])
        });
    }, [entries]);
```

I'd think you can use `useMemo` instead of using state variable `finalEntries` in your case.

See below code snippet.

```
  const entries = type == 'admin' ? AdminMenu : CitizenMenu;

  const finalEntries = useMemo(() => {
    return entries?.top?.map(element => element.permission === 'all' || user?.permissions?.includes(element?.permission));
  }, [entries?.top, user?.permissions]);
```